# Error encoding arguments: invalid BigNumber string after deploying to Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, struct, bignumber

I wanna create a system allowing a company to save several data in the contract, and at the same time many companies can save data in this system.

So I create the mapping of struct, and there's array to allow several data correspond to their index stored in one struct.

But when I deployed it on Remix, and wanna stored with function **saveStandard**, it appears the following error:

```
transact to Storage.saveStandard errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="0.2", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.4.1)
```

what happened to my following code?

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Storage{
    
    struct UserInfo {
        uint index;
        string[] time;
        string[] source;
        uint[] emission;
    }
    mapping (string => UserInfo) public users;

    function saveStandard(uint input_material, uint weight, string memory input_time, string memory input_source) 
    public returns (string memory, uint, uint, string memory){
    
        uint id = users[input_source].index + 1;
        users[input_source].index = id;
        
        users[input_source].time[id] = input_time;
        uint Combustion = weight * input_material;
        uint Process = weight * input_material;//input_material is the emission factor
        users[input_source].emission[id] = Combustion + Process;
        
        return (input_source, Combustion, Process, input_time);
    }
    
    
    function search(string memory input_source) public view returns (uint, string memory) {
        uint id = 0;
        while (id <= users[input_source].index) {
            id += 1;
            return (users[input_source].emission[id], users[input_source].time[id]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find out where the problem is.

when I input the `input_material` in ABI. I enter it in decimal form, but it seems like the decimal isn't supported.

When I enter it in integer form, it worked.